# How to distribute oauth2 client app?

Tags: java, android, oauth-2.0

I've written an android app to get my account usage such as Voice data usage, SMS data usage from Ringplus site (ringplus.net).

Ringplus API (https://docs.ringplus.net/) uses Oauth2. And the app that I wrote has hard coded client id & secret for my account.

Now, everything works fine for my account. But I want to give this app to my friend so that he can also use it to view his account usage.

With client id & secret hardcoded, how would that work for my friend?

Also, when I created app in Ringplus website, I just added redirect_uri as something which does not exist like http://localhost since I don't have anything hosted.

So, my question is how do I distribute my app with client id & secret hard coded?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am not wrong the client ID and secret are for the API access. That one cannot be replaced and needs to be present for the application to successfully authentication / authorize with the API.

If you are not keen on sharing you client id and secret than you can provide a preferences screen in the android app, for the user to enter that information. But the user would need to sign up for the API (as you did). Use the information entered in the SharedPreferences can be use to connect to the API.

Comment: Just to clarify, I don't mind hard coding my apps client id & secret values in the code. Are you saying that with those hard coded values, even if I give the app to friend, it'll work with his account to get the stats? I thought it may not work....Note that my Ringplus user & password will be different than his. And in my account, I've created the application from which I'm grabbing client & secret & hard coded it. I thought it'll not work when he'll authenticate for the first time via webview using my hard coded client and secret. Can you clarify a bit?

Comment: The solution for hard coding is not ideal especially when you want your application to be into production but during the development and testing stage it can be an option. Apart from that, (as per the API) "Retrieve Authorization Code", when it is called will take the users to an authentication page which will ask the user for their username and password (or whatever information they require for authentication), once the authentication is complete based on the param passed for callback, it will be redirected back to your application.

Comment: yes, once its authenticated, it'll be redirected back to app, but my redirect uri is just dummy (https://localhost) as I don't have anything as such. And I've written this app just for dev purpose & not production. Are you saying that would it still work in this case?

Comment: do you get the authentication screen when you start your app?

Comment: this url explain a bit, on how you can use the callback for oauth 2.0. https://energimolnet.wordpress.com/2013/05/08/energimolnet-android-oauth2-sample/ .. The api used is not the same as yours but it shows how you can use the intent to listen from the callback. It should be defined in your manifest file.

Comment: Yes, I'm using webview & I can see Ringplus website auth screen for one time where I click "Authorize app" & then read code value & then get access token, etc. And I can then invoke API calls as well to get stats. But my question was if I share this app to my friend, will he be able to get his stats as well via his account in Ringplus??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91336/discussion-between-freephone-panwal-and-dilberted).

Answer (score 0):

You should store client secret in a server. Upon receiving the code by  sending clientid to ringplus you will get code to your server redirect uri. From here you can send the client secret to ringplus and send authentication token to the user